# CoffeeScript Dom Functions

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

What is the equivalent of this jQuery code in coffeeScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                alert($("#w3s").attr("href"));
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a href="http://www.google.com" id="w3s">Google.com</a></p>
        <button>Show href Value</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

PS: I know any kind of Javascript can work as Coffee-Script, but I want to learn the Coffee-Script syntax for this code.
Thank you...

Comment: [js2coffee.org](http://js2coffee.org/) can help you

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but it doesnt help me. it gives me almost the same code with jQuery.

Comment: You're probably going to attract some down votes just for mentioning http://w3fools.com so you might want to change that.

Comment: if you are right, and somebody votes me down just for site name, i can call them politely "stupid". I will edit it thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The strict translation of your code would look like this:

```
$ ->
  $("button").click (e)->
    alert $("#w3s").attr("href")
```

However, I prefer the following backbone-esque style. I took some liberties with your html to wrap the `p` and `button` tags in a div so that you can manage it as a component. The obvious advantage here is the abstraction of individual DOM components that can be reused and each component has its own context. Because of the ease of use of coffeescript classes, it makes it very natural:

```
class window.ButtonAndLink
    constructor: (el)->
      @$el = $(el)
      # optionally, cache the href
      # @href = @$el.find('a').attr('href')
      @addListeners()

    addListeners: ->
      @$el.find('button').on 'click', @handleClick

    handleClick: (e)=>
      alert @$el.find('a').attr('href')
      # optionally, use the cached value
      # alert @href

$ ->
  $('.link-and-button').each (index, div)->
    new window.ButtonAndLink(div)
```

html slightly reworked

```
<div class="link-and-button">
  <p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com" id="w3s">W3Schools.com</a></p>
  <button>Show href Value</button>
</div>
```

working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9bj2oj9t/

Comment: I can't believe you use 11 lines of (subjectivity ugly) code to do the same thing you can do in 2 lines.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker clearly the words reuse and context were lost on you. That is just a template for creating components that are dynamically scoped. I appreciate the downvote though. haters gonna hate.

Comment: fwiw, I have several 10k line javascript apps that have a 1 line `document.ready` function, because of abstractions like this.

Comment: My point isn't so much whether or not this is a good "pattern", but rather whether it is appropriate for this question; sometimes a simple function is better than a class, since not all apps are 10k line apps. I'm all for providing more information in that the OP didn't ask for when appropiate, but IMHO this is "too much information", since the question has all the appearance of a simple problem. What it too often leads to is people copying this sort of code in places that are not appropriate... Also, I'm not in favour of spoonfeeding these sort of questions, little or no explanation...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I guess I read the OP's comment 'almost the same code with jQuery' as being underwhelmed with the obvious and an inquiry to other patterns that might be available. To me having structure in the language by default, instead of by dependency (like backbone in js) is one of the major features of the language. I can't help him being underwhelmed by a simple jquery function. I'm just doing my best to rid the world of functional spaghetti, one SO question at a time.